# ScrollView does not scroll unless window is resized in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, macos, scrollview, scrollbar, maui

I am new to .NET MAUI.

I have a scroll view and inside the scroll view I have a Vertical Stack Layout with 2 items, a label and a button.

```
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        x:Name="Stack"
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Label
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
            x:Name="ThirdButton"
            Text="Create Label"
            Clicked="OnCreateClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Start" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When the button is clicked, I add labels to the stack dynamically.

```
private void OnCreateClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label { Text = "This is a new label" };
    Stack.Add(label);
}
```

What I expect to happen is when the content size of the StackLayout is bigger than the size of the ScrollView, the scrollbar appear and I can scroll the view.

However it is not happening. I need to resize the window at least a few pixels in order to get the scrollbar appear and able to scroll the view.

Using:

macOS 13.1
Visual Studio 2022 for Mac
.NET 7

Target platform: Mac(MacCatalyst)

I have tried with no success:

1. setting the HorizontalScrollbarVisibility to "Always"
2. setting the HorizontalOption to "FillandExpand"

I was also searching the documentation for any other solution but did not find any.

I would appreciator any help.

Thank you.

Comment: is this scrollview directly inside a content page or inside any other control that might affect it?

Comment: @tataelm yes the ScrollView is inside a ContentPage directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code:

In .xaml, name the **Scrollview**

```
<ScrollView x:Name="myscroll">
```

Then in .cs file, when add the label:

```
private void OnCreateClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label { Text = "This is a new label" };
    Stack.Add(label);
    // Signals that the measure value of this View must be recomputed 
    (myscroll as IView).InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. It is solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my maui-ios workload to 7.0.92 and the broken scrolling on iOS is fixed for me. In 7.0.86 it was broken and not scrolling.

Fixed in this commit it seems:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/commit/e8835a46a9e3b3995056f49aa2750df0d0d22c28